# Не запускается контейнер lxc

Tags: linux, debian, lxc

(Linux debian 4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.152-1 (2020-10-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
lxc-start --version 3.0.3)

При запуске возникает такая ошибка

## lxc-start -n myContainer -d

lxc-start: myContainer: lxccontainer.c: wait_on_daemonized_start: 833 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state

lxc-start: myContainer: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 330 The container failed to start

lxc-start: myContainer: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 333 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode

lxc-start: myContainer: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 336 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options

Или такая

## lxc-start -d -n --logpriority=debug myContainer

lxc-start: --logpriority=debug: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 290 No container config specified

Answer (score 0):

```
  -f, --rcfile=FILE      Load configuration file FILE
```

Где конфигурация контейнера?

Какая версия LXC?
Что показывает dmesg?